# RxJava null fields and optionals

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

I have a somewhat philosophical (Or maybe just ignorant) question.

**Basically the question is:** Should we, or should we not, go "full-reactive" and what does "full-reactive" means?

A simple example of why the question came to my mind.

Imagine that we make an API call that some elements maybe are null. Example:

```
Observable<Result<Profile>> loadUserProfile(@Nullable String userId)
```

*Note: Result is the state of the operation (LOADING, SUCCESS, ERROR)*

Now, as far as I can see we can approach the nullability of the userId with two options: (Note: I'm using pseudo-code here)

**Option 1:** Kinda not "full-reactive" ?

```
Observable<Result<Profile>> loadUserProfile(@Nullable String userId) {
  if (userId is null) {
     return Result.error("Something really bad is happening");
  } else {
     return ProfileApi.loadUserProfile(userId)
             .map(profile -> Result.success(profile);
  }
}
```

**Option 2:** Approaching the use case with Optional values (https://medium.com/@joshfein/handling-null-in-rxjava-2-0-10abd72afa0b)

```
Observable<Result<Profile>> loadUserProfile(@Nullable String userId) {
   return Observable.just(new Optional<>(userId))
      .flatMap(ProfileApi.loadUserProfile(userId))
      .map(profile -> Result.success(profile)
}
```

For both cases the result of the userId being null is to send a Result.error("Something really bad happening")

What option would you prefer? Or maybe you would prefer **Option 3** *[insert option here]* ?

Sorry if it was a dumb question. I kinda feel it was but we'll see :)
Anyway thanks for reading.

**Conclusions:** So far, from what have been discussed, it seems that either approach would be considered reactive way and it's just a matter of how you feel it suits best your style of coding.

Comment: Is it possible that user has null id? What you expect in your application if this happens (null id)?

Comment: I used the userId just as an example. Could have been with something different.

Comment: So, "Should we, or should we not..." depends on your expectations.

Comment: For the use case i'm describing we assume the userId can be null.

Comment: Ok, then what should happen in your application if userId is null? What you expect in this case"?

Comment: It should throw an error state to the UI. Represented by the Result.error(""). I also updated the question to describing what should happen in case of error. Thanks for that

Comment: Will the second option that you described (Option 2) throw an error state to the UI?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154786/discussion-between-yazon2006-and-peddro).

Answer (score 0):

The problematic you're facing is based on *existance* or *nullability*. So let's assume something:

> Everything that is not expected is an error, therefore it should throw an exception

Based on this premise this becomes a question easy to answer. Following with your example:

```
Observable<Result<Profile>> loadUserProfile(@Nullable String userId) {
  if (userId is null) {
     return Observable.error(new UserIdIsNullException())
  } else {
     return ProfileApi.loadUserProfile(userId)
             .map(profile -> Result.success(profile);
  }
}
```

This way you're using all the power of `Observable`s. You'll just need to catch those errors in your UI and render the corresponding state

Comment: The option you did is something that the Option 2 does (as it is shown in the link I've sent). Basically it throws an exception if the userId is null. But now comes the question: If we want to make a fully-reactive app, doesn't that if break the concept?

So to be just reactive it should be part of the stream with the Optional object surrounding the userId

Comment: Throwing an error is just another tool you have into your reactive toolbox. You can either let it go through all your pipe until it reaches the `subscribe` method or you can catch it earler, handle it gracefully and transform it into something that fits your stream

Comment: So basically there's no harm in making the if as long as the return is something that fits the reactive stream.